# How to log in in ftp account using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, ftp

I want to log in to an **ftp account** and display the files or directories in fileview control.

What is the best approach to do it?

I am able to do it but some security issues are arises like if you are using your username and password in the **URL**, the location of the file also displays your credentials you've provided..

I want to connect the fileview without loging in in the log in dialog that appears.

Comment: +1....See OPs reputations.....its 1. Perhaps he is new here and may need to learn how to ask questions and give some stuff in support of his questions. Then why downvote....I request OP to show some code that has been tried.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at this FTP client + control:

http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/client/an-ftpclient-class-and-winform-control

Comment: Im sorry sirs/maams, Yeah i am new here and i just want to try asking question here. By the way to make it more clear to everyone here, Is there anyone who already used fileview control of LogicNP from ssware.com here? I tried to use their support page to find the answer to my question but its a badluck. I have a fileview control and i want to display the directories and file from my ftp account. I am able to do it without loging in to the log in pop I set the currentfolder of the fileview to something like this fileview1.CurreontFolder = "ftp://username:password@fakesite.com"

Comment: With this i can display the item inside my ftp account using fileview control but when i right click on the item and choose properties my account credentials appears on the location are of the item security concern in short. I don't want that to happen. Then I tried another method like

Comment: fileview1.currentfolder = "ftp://username@fakesite.com" This method shows the pop up log in you need to enter your username and password before the fileview can display the items inside your ftp account. When i right click on the item and check for the location it shows something like this ftp://username@fakesite.com/sample.txt this is almost enough for me but i don't want the pop up login dialog to appear. Is there anyway to do it? please help and thank you in advance.